# Is there a way to add a countdown to a .net console?

Tags: c#

I am learning c# and I was trying to test my abilities by making a short game using the .net framework console. I want to make it so that if you don't type "(the thing the player needs to type)" within x amount of time, then they fail, and they go to the death screen.

I have tried looking up stuff like the System.Threading.CountdownEvent, Systen.Threading.Timer and System.Timers.Timer etc, but all the tutorials don't help.

```
        tutorialfight:
            if (fight == "Y")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Goblin: 'You seem week, hit me first!'");
            }
            else if (fight == "N")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is the tutorial, you have no choice, Would you like to fight? (Y/N)");
                fight = Console.ReadLine();
                goto tutorialfight;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Type Y for yes or N for no");
                fight = Console.ReadLine();
                goto tutorialfight;
            }
            int goblinhp = 5;
            Console.WriteLine("Misery: 'Type what is says to do some damage. If you fail, you take some damage, and if you dont kill the enemy within the amount of time allowed, you die!'");
            Console.WriteLine("Type 'x3hu' in 10 seconds to deal 1 damage");
            string x3hu = Console.ReadLine();
            if (x3hu != "x3hu")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your health went down 3 points!");
                health = health - 3;
                Console.WriteLine("Health: " + health);
                Console.WriteLine("Misery: 'Dont worry, you've still got loads of health left!'");
            }
            else
            {
                goblinhp = goblinhp - 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Goblin health: " + goblinhp);
                Console.WriteLine("Misery: 'Great job!'");
            }
```

Comment: Side note: I would consider removing any `goto`s.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you already have a grasp of what you need:

1. Some way of detecting Console input is available to read
2. Some way of setting a timeout for user input

You should be able to accomplish this by using the `Console.KeyAvailable` property and tracking the elapsed time of a `Stopwatch`.

The pseudo code would go something like this:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("You have 10 seconds to press attack (x)");
var timeout = 10;
StopWatch.Start();

while(Stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds < timeout && !Console.KeyAvailable)
{
    // wait
}

// process which event happened first
```

The conditions and looping logic could vary but this should be enough to get you headed in the right direction :)

[KeyAvailable documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.keyavailable?view=netframework-4.8)

[Stopwatch documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple solution based on Dawid Owens' answer.

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var timeout = 10;
        var textToWrite = "Hello World!";
        bool isTimeIsUp = false;
        bool returnPressed = false;
        StringBuilder enteredText = new StringBuilder();

        Console.WriteLine($"You have {timeout} seconds to write: '{textToWrite}'");
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        while (!returnPressed)
        {
            while (!isTimeIsUp && !Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                isTimeIsUp = stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds >= timeout;
            }
            if (isTimeIsUp) break;

            var ch = Console.ReadKey();
            returnPressed = ch.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter;
            if (!returnPressed)
            {
                enteredText.Append(ch.KeyChar);
            }
        }

        if (isTimeIsUp || enteredText.ToString() != textToWrite)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\nFailure!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\nSuccess!");
        }
    }
}
```